# exiftoolでコマンド使用できていたのに、exiftool.exeと打たなければ画面スクロールするようになった理由は？

Tags: windows

**環境**
・OS - Windows10
・配置階層 - L:\hoge\exiftool.exe
・システム環境変数Path - L:\hoge

---

**これまで**
コマンドプロンプト起動後、普通に実行できていました

```
C:\Users\user>exiftool コマンド内容
```

---

**現在**
・コマンドプロンプト起動後、コマンドを打つと画面が無限スクロールします
・1行しかコマンドを打っていないのですが、何行も繰り返し打った状態になります

```
C:\Users\user>exiftool コマンド内容
C:\Users\user>exiftool コマンド内容
C:\Users\user>exiftool コマンド内容
C:\Users\user>exiftool コマンド内容
```

Ctrl+cを押すと、下記表示になります

```
^Cバッチ ジョブを終了しますか (Y/N)?
```

「exiftool」の代わりに「exiftool.exe」とコマンドを打つと、以前のように普通に実行されます

---

**質問**
・(Windows再起動なども行っていないのに)exiftoolではなく、exiftool.exeと打たなければならなくなった理由は何ですか？
・1行コマンド打っただけなのに、何行もコマンドが続けて入力される理由として何が挙げられますか？

Comment: exiftool.bat が生成されていませんか？

Comment: exiftool.bat を別途自分で作成しました。もしかするとこのファイルが影響しているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> exiftool.bat を別途自分で作成しました。もしかするとこのファイルが影響しているのでしょうか？

exiftool.bat が悪さをしています。もしカレントディレクトリ直下に exiftool.bat があるのだとすれば、コマンドプロンプトで `exiftool` と打って起動するのは `L:\hoge\exiftool.exe` ではなく `.\exiftool.bat` です。

Comment: カレントディレクトリ直下にあった exiftool.bat ファイルを削除したら、以前のように(exiftool と打って)正常動作するようになりました

Answer (score 4):

`where` コマンドで(実行)ファイルを検索する方法もあります。

引数に指定したファイル名を、デフォルトではカレントディレクトリと環境変数 PATH の値が指すフォルダから検索します。Linuxにおける `which` コマンドに少し似ているかもしれません。

```
C:\>where notepad
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

参考:
[Windowsのwhereコマンドでファイルを探す：Tech TIPS - ＠IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0904/10/news115.html)

余談として、実行環境のOSを問わず、バッチファイルを作成する際は既存のコマンドと重複した名前は避けた方が余計なトラブルに巻き込まれずに済みます。